# Draw three colors with replacement $M$ times. What is the probability that number of reds is more than number of greens.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose we draw three colors from the an urn with replacement. The color are red, green, and black. The probability of drawing each is given by $p$, $q$ and $r$, respectively. The balls are  drawn independently.

Suppose we make $M$ draws.  Let denote the number of reds by $R$, the number of greens by $G$, and the number of blacks by $B$.

Question: what is the probability that the number of reds is strictly greater than the number of greens?

I think we can start as follows:
\begin{align}
P(R >G)& = \sum_{k = 0}^M P(R >G|R=k) P(R=k) \\
\end{align}
I think $R(R=r)$ is binomial specifically,
\begin{align}
P(R=k) = C(M,r)  p^k (q+r)^{M-k}
\end{align}

However, I am having trouble computing $P(R >G|R=k)$. I have an intuition that $G$ give $R=k$ should be binomial with $M-k$  but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a really nice closed formula for this.

It is $$P(G<R)=\sum_{a=1}^M\sum_{b=0}^{a-1}P(R=a\land G=b)$$

Now, $$\begin{align}  P(R=a\land G=b)&=\binom{M}{a}\binom{M-a}{b}p^aq^br^{M-a-b}\\&=\binom M{a,b,M-a-b}p^aq^br^{M-a-b},\end{align}$$ where the second formula uses the multinomial.

But there really isn't a closed formula.

You just get:

$$P(G<R)=\sum_{a=1}^{M}\sum_{b=0}^{a-1} \binom M{a,b,M-a-b}p^aq^br^{M-a-b}$$

Of course, if $a+b>M,$ the multinomial is zero, so you can don't need all the terms. You can instead write it as:

$$\sum_{c=1}^{M}\sum_{0\leq b<c/2}\binom{M}{b,c-b,M-c}p^{c-b}q^br^{M-c}$$

where $c$ is the total of red and green colors.

---

Even if $r=0$ - that is, if there are really only two colors - there isn't really a nice closed formula. Then you get:

$$\sum_{0\leq b<M/2} \binom Mb p^{M-b}q^b$$
This is the left side of the binomial expansion of $(p+q)^{M},$ but there is no known closed formula other than ones which use "special functions" which essentially are defined as this value.